# Checking UAC whitelist?

Tags: windows, uac

The program I'm using is dumping log-files which I'm then later unable to write to, if the program even manages to pick up the files. The problem doesn't seem to occur on machines where the infamous User Account Control is disabled, but I'm wondering if it's possible to find a list somewhere of the programs accepted by the UAC?

Comment: Your program is not on the whitelist. The problem is that the log files require administrator access to write to them, and your program is not running elevated.

Comment: Infamous?  I *love* UAC.  It makes programmers pay attention.  Ten years ago most software wouldn't run properly if you weren't an administrator; nowadays, most software does, and that's because of UAC.  In your case, consider whether the log files should in fact be restricted to administrators; do they contain sensitive information?  If so, the program processing the log files should be configured to require elevation.  If not, the process generating the log files should be putting them somewhere else, or explicitly setting the permissions.